"TypeError: r is not a function" during a Next JS build
I encountered this error while building my app in NextJS 14.1.0.
This is the error during build:
Generating static pages (0/15)  [=   ]TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)

Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)

Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
TypeError: r is not a function
    at 20936 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:218616)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 64042 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:9:228901)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 19362 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:550879)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 75662 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:425579)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 69698 (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\chunks\461.js:32:429440)
    at t (D:\Projects\MyNextJSProject\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)

When I run npm run dev, it runs okay, with some warnings on Formidable saying that:
⨯ node_modules\formidable\src\Formidable.js (15:17) @ hexoid 
⨯ TypeError: hexoid is not a function

I don't know if that last information would help, but I'd include it just in case. Please advise, what should I do to solve the build error? Thank you!
EDIT: I found that the error comes from Pubnub (Which uses formidable package that gives me the error/warning above). As soon as I remove <PubNubProvider> from my provider.js, the build completed with no error. But now, how do I make Pubnub compatible with my app? I'm using pubnub 7.6.3 and pubnub-react 3.0.2.

Please provide us your code so we can look into it for any apparent errors.


TypeError: hexoid is not a function

The error is related to the formidable package.
I adapted this solution for nextJS:
https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/issues/352#issuecomment-1866116368
After adjusting the config, the error disappeared:
next.config.mjs
import path from 'path';
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.alias['hexoid'] = path.resolve('node_modules/hexoid/dist/index.js');
        return config;
      }
};

export default nextConfig;

